# Ionic: Modify ion nav bar buttons from inside a ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

in our app we implemented our own split view using `ui-view` to load the right side pane. We implemented our own because the `Ionic` way of showing the side menu wasn't enough for us. This is how it looks like:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwH97.png)

The problem is that the buttons specified in the right pane view aren't added to the `header` bar since that view isn't the root `ion-view`, it's inside a `ui-view`.

This is how the DOM looks like with our split view:

```
<ion-nav-view>
  <ion-view> <!-- Left pane ion-view -->
    <mm-split-view> <!-- Our directive -->
      <div class="mm-split-pane-menu"> <!-- Left pane items -->
      <div ui-view="mmaMessagesIndex"> <!-- Right pane container, ui-view -->
        <ion-view> <!-- Right pane ion-view -->
          <ion-nav-buttons> <!-- These buttons aren't shown -->`
```

I looked at the `ionNavButtons` directive and I saw that it looks for the parent `ionView`, and in this case it isn't the root `ionView`. So I decided to create my own directive similar to `ionNavButtons`, but using the outer `ion-view` instead of the parent one.

This had some problems too, since this relies on `beforeEnter` and `afterEvent` events, and when my right side view is loaded the events of the outer view are already fired. So I decided to trigger it myself:

```
parentViewCtrl.beforeEnter(undefined, {transitionId: transitionId});
```

With this I managed to make it work **the first time I open the view**. But if I go to a subview (let's call it view B) and then come back, the header bar shown is the one from the subview (view B), not the one I want (view A). The same happens if I use the side menu to go to another view (view C) and then come back to view A, the header seen is the one from view C.

Anybody knows how to make the `header` bar update when going back to the view?

I know my solution is pretty hacky and I guess no one will know how to help me, but I'd appreciate any advice on how to make something like this work.

Some useful links:

[Directive I created based on ionNavButtons.](https://github.com/dpalou/moodlemobile2/blob/4c6de0978613dd54a2ee05730da55b77e5b61f42/www/core/directives/navbuttons.js)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was because I was using a wrong `transitionId`. When going back to the view a new `transitionId` is generated, and I needed to use that one. I use `beforeEnter` event to get the new `transitionId`.